# Notification Time in Google Calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I created an alarm in android Google Calendar at 2:25 PM. And then I tried to capture the Event Alarm intent however when I format the alarm time it is showing a different time.

Here is my log

```
  10-31 14:25:18.475: D/@@@@@ Notify(25637): event name: New event
  10-31 14:25:18.475: D/@@@@@ Notify(25637): alarm time formatted: 2013-10-31 02:11
  10-31 14:25:18.475: D/@@@@@ Notify(25637): alarm time not formatted: 2013-9-31 2:11
  10-31 14:25:18.475: D/@@@@@ Notify(25637): today: 2013-9-31 14:25
  10-31 14:25:18.475: D/@@@@@ Notify(25637): today formatted: 2013-10-31 02:25
  10-31 14:25:18.480: I/CalendarTest(25637): CalendarTest.onReceive called!
```

I use this to format my time

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
```

Do you know why there is a discrepancy?

Edit: unformatted time

```
 Date dtAlarmTime = new Date(alarmTime);
 Calendar alarm_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 alarm_cal.setTime(dtAlarmTime);

 int alarm_year = alarm_cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 int alarm_month = alarm_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 int alarm_day = alarm_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 int alarm_hour = alarm_cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
 int alarm_minute = alarm_cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Comment: How do you print the non-formatted date?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your `SimpleDateFormat`. The problem lies with how `Calendar` stores the month. It starts with `0` as `Calendar.JANUARY`, so your non-formatted month will be displayed 1 less than "the real month".

As for 12-hour vs 24-hour, use `HH` for 24-hour, instead of `hh` in your `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I think I found the reason. 

When I set 15 Minutes Reminder it will get that alarm time and begin time even though the real alarm should be 15 minutes later.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, the alarm is set based on the reminder, not on the real event time. If you want to have alarm at the event time, set the reminder to 0 minutes :)